# Forcing an Alignment to a Specific Part of the Page

Tags: math-mode, align

I know how to align these equations along the equal sign. What I want to do is put the equal sign anywhere on the page I want to, as though I was taking the aligned equations and shifting them left or right. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: just left or right? go the ugly way and add \hspaces to one equation (or any other horizontal spacing, e.g. \quad )

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I didn't realize I could do that with \hspace. I'm off!

Answer (score 1):

Adding an `\hspace` before or after the longest `align` field will shift the whole block 1/2 of the `\hspace` value.  So, in this MWE, after showing the generic `align`, I add a 2in shift first to the left and then to the right of the longest element.  These should result in a net 1" shift of the block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
\hspace{2in}W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\hspace{2in}\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

As seen in the result, enhanced with the PDF measuring tool, the left/right shifts are as predicted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution useing `parbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}\begin{align*}
W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}


\hspace{5cm}\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\begin{align*}
W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}}


\hspace{-5cm}\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\begin{align*}
W&=\frac{4}{3}\cdot\rho_w\cdot L_s\int\displaylimits_1^3(3-x)xdx\\
W&=78480J\int\displaylimits_1^3(3x-x^2)dx\\
W&=261600J
\end{align*}}
\end{document}
```